# Clicking on a button to display .CHM help file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, chm, helpfile

I want to display a .CHM help file when clicking on a button in VB.NET. Could anyone show me code how to do this?

```
Private Sub cmdHelp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Objects, Byval e As System.EventArgs)Handles cmdHelp.Click
   'Please help provide some code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a Process.Start with a verb of `open` does the trick:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New Process()
        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("path to my CHM file")
        psi.Verb = "open"
        p.StartInfo = psi
        p.Start()

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that `.chm` files are heavily restricted by the OS from about WinXP SP3 (SP2?) onwards - they are considered to be a reasonble security risk, so you can't open them directly from a network or remote location. You will need to code accordingly, and expect exceptions when trying to open them.

Answer (score 9):

The .NET API offers the `Help` class in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.  Some examples:

```
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "HelpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.TableofContents, Nothing)
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "HelpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, Nothing)
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "HelpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.Topic, "Page.html")
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "HelpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, 123)
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "HelpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.Keyword, "Keyword")
```

Answer (score 1):

on Button click event write this code

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("hh.exe " & App.HelpFile, vbNormalFocus)
```

Where hh.exe is any name App.Helpfile is your chm file name

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HH.EXE to display a specified topic.

In the example code
replace `[topicid]` with the real topic id
and replace `[yourhelpfile.chm]` with the full path and name of your .chm file

If a return value is required

```
Dim RetVal As Integer = Shell("HH.EXE -mapid [topicid] ms-its:[yourhelpfile.chm]", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

otherwise just this

```
Shell("HH.EXE -mapid [topicid] ms-its:[yourhelpfile.chm]", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```